# Celery task logging multuple times - best practice for logger call

Tags: python, logging, celery

please what is the best practice to use logger in celery? I am using Celery and Beat for task scheduling and it seems, that program is getting multiple instances of logger because it creates each message multiple times. First of all, it will create one message, after another call there are two messages, after that three, like this:

> [2021-02-21 11:21:00,058: INFO/MainProcess] Received task:
> exampleproject.tasks.task_example[xxxxxx]   [2021-02-21 11:21:00,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] 2021-02-21 11:21:00,467 [INFO]: Nothing to
> schedule [2021-02-21 11:21:00,468: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task
> exampleproject.tasks.task_example[xxxxxx] succeeded in
> 0.4075276150251739s: None
>
> [2021-02-21 11:22:00,058: INFO/MainProcess] Received task:
> exampleproject.tasks.task_example[yyyy]   [2021-02-21 11:22:00,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] 2021-02-21 11:22:00,467 [INFO]: Nothing to
> schedule [2021-02-21 11:22:00,468: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7]
> 2021-02-21 11:22:00,467 [INFO]: Nothing to schedule [2021-02-21
> 11:22:00,468: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task
> exampleproject.tasks.task_example[yyyy] succeeded in
> 0.4075276150251739s: None
>
> [2021-02-21 11:23:00,058: INFO/MainProcess] Received task:
> exampleproject.tasks.task_example[aaaa]   [2021-02-21 11:23:00,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] 2021-02-21 11:23:00,467 [INFO]: Nothing to
> schedule [2021-02-21 11:23:00,468: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7]
> 2021-02-21 11:23:00,467 [INFO]: Nothing to schedule [2021-02-21
> 11:23:00,468: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] 2021-02-21 11:23:00,467
> [INFO]: Nothing to schedule [2021-02-21 11:23:00,468:
> INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task exampleproject.tasks.task_example[aaaa]
> succeeded in 0.4075276150251739s: None

It always creates another message of **[INFO]: Nothing to schedule** each call. It should create only one message. What I have wrong here, please? I am using crontab schedule for beat for one minute '*/1'

Here is my **tasks.py** file:

```
from pathlib import Path

from celery import shared_task

import myproject.log as log
from myproject.scheduler import main as example_fuction


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


@shared_task(ignore_result=True)
def task_example():
    logger = log.get_logger('my_schedule', (BASE_DIR / 'log' / 'my_schedule').with_suffix('.log'))
    my_variable = example_fuction()
    if bool(my_variable):
        logger.info(f'Example log message: {my_variable}')
    else:
        logger.info('Nothing to schedule')
```

Here is my **log.py** file:

```
import logging
import sys
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

FORMATTER = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s')


def get_console_handler():
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
    return console_handler


def get_file_handler(log_file):
    file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, when='midnight')
    file_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
    return file_handler


def get_logger(logger_name, log_file):
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # better to have too much log than not enough

    logger.addHandler(get_console_handler())
    logger.addHandler(get_file_handler(log_file))

    # with this pattern, it's rarely necessary to propagate the error up to parent
    logger.propagate = False

    return logger
```

I will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in **log.py**, check with `if not logger.handlers` - can be it done like this, or is there better solution?

```
def get_logger(logger_name, log_file):
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

    if not logger.handlers:
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # better to have too much log than not enough

        logger.addHandler(get_console_handler())
        logger.addHandler(get_file_handler(log_file))

        # with this pattern, it's rarely necessary to propagate the error up to parent
        logger.propagate = False

    return logger
```